# HTTPGet Action Method gets error messages

Tags: c#, crud, http-get

I was trying to use the `HttpGet` Action Method but I got an error message.
I followed the tutorial from [this Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qjR25bEsWs) to make a CRUD app but I got 2 error messages so I copied the code from [here](https://www.codewithmukesh.com/blog/blazor-crud-with-entity-framework-core/#Generating_/_Migrating_the_Database) but it did not make a difference.

I also installed the NuGet Packages `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` and `System.Net.Http` thinking that maybe I have the problems because a package was missing but it did not help either.

Below is the code under `PeopleController.cs`:

```
using CuriousDriveTutorial.Data.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CuriousDriveTutorial.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class PeopleController: ControllerBase
    {
        //dependancy injection for applicationdbcontext
        private readonly ApplicationDBContext context1;
        public PeopleController(ApplicationDBContext context) { this.context1 = context; }
    }

    //get action method
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get() => await context1.People.ToListAsync();

}
```

And below are the error messages for line 22 ( `public async Task<IActionResult> Get() => await context1.People.ToListAsync();` ):

- > 1. CS0116    A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods.
- > 2. CS0103    The name 'context1' does not exist in the current context.

The red *squiggly* line is under the words `Get` and `context1`. Also, I don't know if this information is useful but the project is a Blazor app.

Comment: Your `//get action method` with the accompanying code must be inside the class `PeopleController`

Answer (score 1):

You close the class `PeopleController` in line 18, thus the method `Get` isn't part of the class anymore. In C# functions can't be members of namespaces directly. For the same reason it has no access to the variable `context1`.

Solution: Move the brace from line 18 to line 23.

Comment: I did but I was still having problems so I changed line 22 to `public async Task<IActionResult> Get() => (IActionResult)await context1.People.ToListAsync();`

Comment: Ah, I didn't check that part. Yeah, a List is not an IActionResult object, so that cast may still give you errors during execution. Usually you would return something like `Ok(await ...)`, so your API will return a status `200 OK` with the list in the response's body.

Answer (score 1):

Get() method is defined outside of your `PeopleController` class.
You should define your method inside your class.
Like this.

```
public SomeClass
{
  //blur
  public void SomeMethod()
  {
       //do nothing.
  }
}
```